# Write a list of different types to a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable of list, `airMod`, consisting of different types of data: *char, uint32, and float*. Here is how it looks like in my visual studio code debug mode:

[image]

Now I'd like to save it in a binary file(raw buffer. I will use C++ to process it byte by byte). I am wondering how I should do it. I searched how it should be done, but mostly the solution of save a list containing same data type (ex. `bytearray`, `to_byte`.....).

I would like to save the data, then process it in C++ ((`fseek, tellg, ifstream`, etc. ).Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary file"?

Comment: What do you mean by "binary file"? If you're thinking "you know, something stored on the hard drive as ones and zeroes", all files are stored that way.

Comment: @Roseman: raw buffer. in Bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in `struct` module, described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

You can use it to serialize a set of objects (often numbers) to bytes.  For example:

```
import struct

with open('outfile', 'wb') as out:
    out.write(struct.pack('<if', 123, 456.789))
```

That will write an 8 byte file which can be interpreted using a C or C++ struct like this, assuming you're on a little-endian machine like x86:

```
struct MyRecord {
    int32_t x;
    float y;
};
```

When defining such a struct in C or C++, you must take care about the alignment, padding, and endianness of the fields.  `__attribute__((packed))__` is useful if you use GCC or Clang and might have unaligned fields.

Another option in Python is to use a NumPy "structured array".  You can create one like this:

```
import numpy as np
rec = np.array([100, 456.789], [('x', 'i4'), ('y', 'f4')])
with open('outfile', 'wb') as out:
    out.write(rec.tobytes())
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use NumPy like this: `vec = np.array(airMod)
with open(file, 'wb') as out:
    out.write(vec.tobytes())`

However, it says "'list' object has no attribute 'tobytes'
"

Comment: @NickXTsui: You must be running some other code, because the code you wrote in that comment works fine.  `vec` is NOT a list, perhaps you are running different code where `vec` is a list.